# Oracle PL/SQL way to conditionally execute a statement based on the results of an environment variable - DB pipelines and Flyway

Tags: oracle, plsql, jenkins-pipeline, flyway

I'm using flyway [Placeholders](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/placeholders-configuration-224003082.html) to conditionally execute statements against specific environments

We have a pipeline check before prod that looks at the schema history tables of QA/Test etc. to make sure that every script ran successfully against **every** previous environment - and fails the pipeline if it hasn't.

This is a requirement passed down by management.

So we unfortunately **cannot** use [ShouldExecute](https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/tutorials/tutorial-injecting-environments) because it will just not execute the whole script.

If we use ShouldExecute - that script will be missing from the schema history table in QA/Test if it is intended to only run against Prod.

So the script itself needs to have that conditional built into it so it can run successfully regardless of whether the statement inside executes.

I thought that maybe the below would work:

```
IF ${environment} = 'test' THEN      
    ALTER TABLE hr.job_history ADD (employee_name VARCHAR2(20 BYTE));    
END IF;
```

which gives

```
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 900
Message    : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Because the above statement only works inside of a function/procedure - **is there an easy way to do this?**

I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630771/check-table-exist-or-not-before-create-it-in-oracle) but I don't know of way to adapt the script for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is conditional compilation, the expression should use the `$IF ... $THEN ... $ELSE ... $END;` syntax, which means that either the code in the $THEN, either the code in the $ELSE clause will be compiled. Doc: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/overview/plsql-conditional-compilation-133587.pdf
The variables are passed using session variable PLSQL_CCFlags, so the variables driven by Flyway should be injected in a prelude where you define it.